# CoreApplicationView vs CoreWindow vs ApplicationView

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

What's the difference between [CoreApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationview.aspx), [CoreWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx),  and [ApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701658) ?

I can see that each has different properties etc. of the app so I'm not asking "which one should I use to get the `abc` property or method?".

I *am* asking what's the logical difference between them. Why have different classes? Since they seem to be more or less the same thing - a class representing the app window.

Comment: The `Core` objects are generally intended for application frameworks to use (XAML, WinJS). Those frameworks then expose the `Core` objects in a way that matches the programming language more closely, For example, `CoreWindow.SizeChanged` becomes the `Window.SizeChanged` event in XAML and the `window.onresize` event in JavaScript. The `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event becomes the `UIElement.KeyDown` event in XAML and the `HTMLElement.onkeydown` event in JavaScript, In general, use the framework objects rather than the core objects.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks.

Comment: @RaymondChen Might be worth putting your comment in an answer :)

Answer (score 10):

There are several differences between the classes you mention. We can distinguish them by two dimensions:

- The structures (see the **From top to bottom** section)
- The functions (see the **For outer or for inner** section)

I've written a post especially for this question, see http://walterlv.github.io/post/core-application-window-of-uwp-en.html.

---

Sometimes we have to view the full class names with namespaces to determine their meanings.

- `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication`
- `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplicationView`
- `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application`
- `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`
- `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window`

Extra, if you're interested in the titlebar,

- `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplicationViewTitleBar`
- `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewTitleBar`

Extra, if you're interested in the threading model,

- `Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher`
- `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer`

We can split them into `Windows.ApplicationModel` and `Windows.UI`, or split them into `Core` and `Xaml`.

The `CoreApplication` and `CoreApplicationView` manage the application model, and the `Application`, `CoreWindow` and `Window` manage the application inner UI. The `CoreApplication`, `CoreApplicationView` and `CoreWindow` manages the core functions, but the `Application` and `Window` manage the XAML UI.

#### From top to bottom

From top to bottom is from `Application` to `Window`, then to XAML. It's obvious that the application contains windows and the window contains the inner XAML UI. Then, what's the real relationship?

The `CoreApplication` manages all the views of a UWP application and the `CoreApplicationView` is the view that it manages directly. A `CoreApplicationView` contains a `CoreWindow` as the window and a `CoreDispatcher` as the threading model.

[image: UWP application view]
▲ UWP application view

You can read [Show multiple views for an app - UWP app developer - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) to learn how to write multiple views applications. You'll know more about the relationship between the `CoreApplication` and the `CoreApplicationView`.

`CoreWindow` is the window that we are all familiar with. 
`Windows.UI.XAML.Window` encapsulate the `CoreWindow` for easier usage. `CoreDispatcher` is the threading model based on the windows message loop. It's the `CoreDispatcher` that keeps the window to show all the time without being disposed.

#### For outer or for inner

Most UWP developers are normal developers, so we should stand on their side to think about the outer and the inner. Normal UWP developers start writing code from `MainPage`, so the outer is out of the page and the inner is the XAML content of the page.

The outer part contains `CoreApplication`, `CoreApplicationView` and `CoreWindow` while the inner part contains `Application` and `Window`. Is it strange that the `Application` and the `Window` are the inner part? The reason is that they manage the XAML part of the application and the window.

The `Window` is the encapsulation of the `CoreWindow` to provide extra XAML UI functions. The same to the `ApplicationView`, it is the encapsulation of the `CoreApplication` providing extra XAML UI functions.

In details, the `CoreWindow` is the class that interop with the Windows Operating System and the UWP application model. It provides those functions such as the window size, location, the input status, etc. The `Window` is the class that provides the ability to use XAML UI for the window, such as setting the XAML content of the window, setting the titlebar of the window, or getting the `Compositor` of the window. The `CoreApplicationView` is the class that interop with the Windows Operating System and provides the mechanism of windows message loop and the ability to change the client area and the non-client area. The `ApplicationView` is the same as the `Window`, provides the ability to use XAML UI for the application.

In conclusion, the `CoreWindow` and the `CoreApplicationView` provide the low-level core functions of the operating system and the application model. The `Window` and the `ApplicationView` encapsulates them for XAML usage.